# add the user id in drupal view page settings url

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am new to DRUPAL. Recently I have created a view with 3 pages. 1st page shows in the main menu tab.
2nd and 3rd page shows in menu tab. Now I would like to display the list of the images uploaded by the user in one of that menu tab. So in order to accomplish this I have added a path like user/%/MY-images
in page settings. Now if I click this menu-tab I am not getting the user id passed in the url.

My contextual filter is working fine. Only thing I need to pass the user id through the URL.

Can anybody help me out to figure the solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your contextual filter you need to set the UID, then you need to add a relationship "the author field", finally in your fields add the uid and make the relationship with the autor (excludes from display) and that's it you will have the images only uploaded by the user.

Please let me know if that works.